# Making pages go live with GitHub

Tags: github, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

How do I make my page go live with github. I mean I can do that I just don’t know how to access the page after setting it live with GitHub.

Comment: I guess you're talking about GitHub Pages. You simply visit the page's URL, which should be of the form `https://<username>.github.io/` and may include a repo name at the end.

Comment: You mean https://ririob.github.io/? The URL is right in the [repo name](https://github.com/ririob/ririob.github.io).

Comment: How did you find OP's GitHub username, @jonrsharpe? I don't see it in their profile.

Comment: @Chris I just searched for "{OP name} github"

Comment: Chris how do you know the username?

Comment: Thanks guys. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how GitHub Pages works.

1. You commit Jekyll code to a repository you control. This is your source and where you make changes if you need to.
2. GitHub has a Jekyll compiler that runs every time you commit to your
   repository.
3. If the code is valid Jekyll code, GitHub copies the compiled code to another location that you don't control.
4. If the code is invalid (failed compile), you will receive an email to your GitHub registered email.

It is this other location (which you don't control) that serves up your site to the world at `https://<username>.github.io`

GitHub Pages help is [here](https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics).